# Dash Navbar with buttons/navlink to open collapse and navigate (combined)

Tags: plotly-dash

I have a Dash page consisting of:

- a body with several dbc.Collapse components that contain graphs, tables, etc.
- a top navbar containing several buttons which trigger (by separate callbacks):

1. The associated collapse group to open/close
2. The browser to navigate to that collapse group

`dbc.NavLink(display_name, id=self.n_id, n_clicks=0, class_name=dn.dbc_menu_fs)`

The callback for navigation, which is the same for all buttons in the navbar looks like this:

```
@app.callback(
    output = Output('url', "href"),
    inputs = [navigation_ids],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def navigate(navs):
    trigger = ctx.triggered_id
    return '/#' + trigger[:-1] + 'CD'
```

The problem I have is that the section scroll below the Navbar by the height of the Navbar, as shown in the picture.

I've tried to reproduce just the navigation with Navlinks, using Navlinks with external_link on/off:
`navs.append(dbc.NavLink("Overview ", href="/#Overview_CD", external_link=False))` 
`navs.append(dbc.NavLink("Overview- ext", href="/#Overview_CD", external_link=True))`

While the external_link=False works perfectly, the external_link=True shows the same navigation effect as the above callback.
I've tried using padding Divs, chaging Navbar 'sticky' and 'fixed' options, etc. but had no luck.
Any clue on how to get my callback (or a .js) reproduce the Navlink with external_link=False?

[page content when navigating with callback or external_link=True](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azAcq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've never done things with `dbc.NavLink` like you are doing above, but I suspect you can achieve a better result using [Dash pages](https://dash.plotly.com/urls). This is the new recommended way to build multi-page apps.

To implement a navbar that won't have the problem like I think I understand you are having with it overlaying your content, you simply define it in the `app.layout` alongside the `dash.page_container`:

`app.py`

```py
navbar = dbc.Navbar(
    dbc.Container(
        [
            # Use row and col to control vertical alignment of logo / brand
            dbc.Row(
                [
                    dbc.Col(
                    # Any compoents you want can go here
                    ),
                    # Another column, etc.
        ]
    ),
    sticky="top", # Maybe unnecessary
)

app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        navbar,
        dash.page_container,
    ],
    className="dbc",
    fluid=True,
)
```

`dash.page_container` is dynamically filled based on the path from layouts defined in `.py` files stored in the `pages` directory.

Each page is registered using `dash.register_page(__name__, path=<path>)`.
So if I want to define a home page:

`pages/home.py`

```py
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import dcc, HTML

dash.register_page(__name__, path="/")
def layout():
    return html.Div([
        dbc.Container([...])
    ])
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick reply. 
This is exactly how I structured my layout (except not using pages). In fact I did it once with the Navbar inside the main container and once outside, no difference. 

The strange thing is that the Navlinks I put within the Navbar to test navigating within the page jump correctly if I set external_link=False (the page does not get hidden behind the Navbar. So the question is, how can I reproduce this behavior within my @app.callback(
    output = Output('url', "href"), where url is the ID of my dcc.Location?

Comment: I understand the frustration of bizarre HTML issues with Dash. If I were you I would try using pages. I've never had a problem with the navbar overlaying the page layout. Otherwise I'd keep looking into the various css options available (like `sticky="top"`, `fluid=True`, etc.)